# C# - Fill a combo box with a DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, datatable, sharpdevelop

I'm used to work with Java where large amounts of examples are available. For various reasons I had to switch to C# and trying to do the following in SharpDevelop:

```
// Form has a menu containing a combobox added via SharpDevelop's GUI

// --- Variables
languages = new string[2];
languages[0] = "English";
languages[1] = "German";
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

// --- Preparation
DataTable lTable = new DataTable("Lang");
DataColumn lName = new DataColumn("Language", typeof(string));
lTable.Columns.Add( lName );
for( int i=0; i<languages.Length; i++ ) {
    DataRow lLang = lTable.NewRow();
    lLang["Language"] = languages[i];
    lTable.Rows.Add(lLang);
}
myDataSet.Tables.Add(lTable);

// --- Handling the combobox
mnuActionLanguage.ComboBox.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["Lang"].DefaultView;
mnuActionLanguage.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Language";
```

One would assume to see some values in the dropdown, but it's empty. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong ;(

*EDIT:
mnuActionLanguage.ComboBox.DataBind() is what I also found on the net, but it doesn't work in my case.*

**SOLUTION**

```
mnuActionLanguage.ComboBox.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```

at the end solved the problem!

Comment: Ah, your using Windows Forms, rather than Web Forms.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to set the binding context of the ToolStripComboBox.ComboBox.

Here is a slightly modified version of the code that I have just recreated using Visual Studio. The menu item combo box is called toolStripComboBox1 in my case. Note the last line of code to set the binding context.

I noticed that if the combo is in the visible are of the toolstrip, the binding works without this but not when it is in a drop-down. Do you get the same problem?

If you can't get this working, drop me a line via my contact page and I will send you the project. You won't be able to load it using SharpDevelop but will with C# Express.

```
var languages = new string[2];
languages[0] = "English";
languages[1] = "German";

DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

// --- Preparation
DataTable lTable = new DataTable("Lang");
DataColumn lName = new DataColumn("Language", typeof(string));
lTable.Columns.Add(lName);

for (int i = 0; i < languages.Length; i++)
{
    DataRow lLang = lTable.NewRow();
    lLang["Language"] = languages[i];
    lTable.Rows.Add(lLang);
}
myDataSet.Tables.Add(lTable);

toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["Lang"].DefaultView;
toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Language";

toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```

Comment: Nice spot, didn't realise the combo was in a toolstrip.

Comment: Me either first time around ;-)

Answer (score 10):

```
string strConn = "Data Source=SEZSW08;Initial Catalog=Nidhi;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
Con.Open();
string strCmd = "select companyName from companyinfo where CompanyName='" + cmbCompName.SelectedValue + "';";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strCmd, Con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
Con.Close();
da.Fill(ds);
cmbCompName.DataSource = ds;
cmbCompName.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
cmbCompName.ValueMember = "CompanyName";
//cmbCompName.DataBind();
cmbCompName.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: You should use parameters

Answer (score 8):

For example, i created a table :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable ();
dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
```

Add recorde to table :

```
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["Title"] = "Price"
row["Value"] = 2000;
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

or :

```
dt.Rows.Add("Price",2000);
```

finally :

```
combo.DataSource = dt;
combo.DisplayMember = "Title";
combo.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you applying a RowFilter to your DefaultView later in the code? This could change the results returned.

I would also avoid using the string as the display member if you have a direct reference the the data column I would use the object properties:

```
mnuActionLanguage.ComboBox.DataSource = lTable.DefaultView;
mnuActionLanguage.ComboBox.DisplayMember = lName.ColumnName;
```

I have tried this with a blank form and standard combo, and seems to work for me.

Comment: No, there is no RowFilter anywhere in the code. It seems that the issue was entirely related to the BindingContext, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

1) "DataBind()" is only for web apps (not windows apps).

2) Your code looks very 'JAVAish' (not a bad thing, just an observation).

Try this:

```
mnuActionLanguage.ComboBox.DataSource = languages;
```

If that doesn't work... then I'm assuming that your datasource is being stepped on somewhere else in the code.

Comment: mnuActionLanguage.ComboBox.DataSource = languages;

doesn't help either, the combobox remains empty. Tkx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
mnuActionLanguage.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Lang.Language";
```

is wrong. Change it to

```
mnuActionLanguage.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Language";
```

and it will work (even without DataBind()).

Comment: Tkx Alan, I tried that too and corrected it above - but the behaviour unfortunately didn't change :( Tkx anyway!

Comment: Well, I copy/pasted your code into VS 2008, fixed it, ran it, and I had 'English' and 'German' in the combobox. Isn't this what you needed?

Comment: Oh, now I see, you also ran into the BindingContext issue and fixed it yourself. Fine then :)