# How Can i Populate Bulk of Data from a DB Table into a Combo Box? - C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, winforms

```
MenuItem menus = new MenuItem();
GridView1.DataSource = menus.GetDataTable();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

menus.GetDataTable() returns a DataTable. In the above case, we are returning to GridView. I need to populate the data into a combo box. How can i do it?

NOTE: Assume GetDataTable only returns records of a single column.

I'm using Winforms

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Fill a combo box with a DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256832/c-fill-a-combo-box-with-a-datatable)

Comment: I wanted to pick your answer as best but i couldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256832/c-fill-a-combo-box-with-a-datatable) helps you.

Comment: Since you are the only, i will pick you as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
    Country countryName = new Country();
    comCountryCus.DataSource = countryName.GetDataFromTable();
    comCountryCus.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w67sdsex%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

K.I.S.S - Keep It Simple & Stupid.