# Find the maximum string in Combobox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to change combobox's DropDownWidth based on maximum string in Combobox's items.
The code below returns the maximum string length from all the items.

```
 Dim maxStringLength As Integer = cboDt.AsEnumerable().
                  SelectMany(Function(row) row.ItemArray.OfType(Of String)()).
                  Max(Function(str) str.Length)
```

cboDt is the datatable  attached to combobox.
I want to return the actual string.
For example if combobox items are:
"aaa"
"bbbb"
"ccccc"
My code returns maxStringLength = 5 (because 5 is the maximum  number of characters of all items-here is ccccc)
I want code to retun "ccccc" (of course in a string variable)

Comment: How many columns does your `DataTable` have, which  are you using in the ComboBox? The rest is not relevant for your `maxStringLength`.

Comment: Just to answer that. My datatable always have two (the display and the value column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the first column of the `DataTable` is displayed in the `ComboBox`:

```
Dim maxStringLength As Integer = cboDt.AsEnumerable().
        Max(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)(0).Length)
```

Note that this assumes that this requires that this column is never `null`.

( I don't see a reason why you would measure the length of the (possibly available) other columns of the table when they aren't shown in the `ComboBox` at all. )

**Update**

> Find the maximum string in Combobox

Now i got it, you want the string not the length:

```
Dim longestString = cboDt.AsEnumerable().
        OrderByDescending(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)(0).Length).
        First().Field(Of String)(0)
```

Comment: the reason is the length of the string and he want to modify the `DropDownWidth` base of the length `:)`

Comment: sir, i guess the OP using a one column only with the [ComboBox and DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/256871/1080742)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Your code returns the .Length, but I want the string. Your note for the columns is correct

Comment: @Nianios, the answer of Mr. Tim is already updated. +1 for you sir.. you have great mind :)

Answer (score 3):

Order the list by string-length descending, and then take the first result.

```
Dim maxStringLength As Integer = 
    cboDt.AsEnumerable().
    SelectMany(Function(row) row.ItemArray.OfType(Of String)()).
    OrderByDescending(Function(str) str.Length).
    First()  ' You can use FirstOrDefault here, if you are
             ' not certain there will be a result.
```

Comment: Error 1 'OrderByDesc' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of String)'.

Comment: I found it :OrderByDescending

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using linq and Finding the Index of `maxStringLength = 5`

```
Dim ls = comboBox4.Items.Cast(Of String)().ToList()
Dim index = ls.FindIndex(Function(c) c.ToString().Count() >= 5)
comboBox4.SelectedIndex = index
```

or using [Max() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx)

```
Dim ls = comboBox4.Items.Cast(Of String)().ToList()
Dim index = ls.Max()
comboBox4.Text = index
```

Comment: I like your idea, unfortunately my Combobox is a third party and it doesn't have the .Items

Comment: ..hows it look like? could you name your _comboBox third party_?

Comment: Sorry my combobox is a component not from Visual Studio. Sorry for any inconvience

Comment: i don't believe that your third party comboBox had no.. or something like [ObjectionCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection(v=vs.71).aspx), but its okay `:)`