# How do i bind data source to a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, sqldatasource, bindingsource

So i currently have two combo boxes. One Being Manufacture the other being model. My sql query looks like this  "Select Distinct Model From sheet1 where (Manufacture =@Manufacture)" this works when i execute it and if i were to fill a datagridtable. But if i try to place this into a combobox i get  System.data.d...... etc for my selections. How can i just have it show the values instead of all this. What am i doing wrong?

```
 private void ManuComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string manu = comboBox3.Text;
        string conStr = "Data Source=CA-INVDEV\\RISEDB01;Initial Catalog=RISEDB01;    Integrated Security=True";
        string sqlcmd = "SELECT DISTINCT Model FROM Sheet1 WHERE (Manufacture =@Manufacture)";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacture", manu);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dr.Close();
                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);                    
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                bindingSource3.DataSource = table;                   
                ModelComboBox.DataSource = bindingSource3;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried setting [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx)?

Comment: i have not. Will try that.

Comment: Im having no luck. How would you recommend i approach ?

Comment: conn.Open(); and conn.Close(); is not needed since you have using.

Comment: thanks sean. Im still a squid :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you give this a try?

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacture", manu);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            IList<string> modelList = new List<string>()
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                modelList.add(dr[0].ToString());
            }

            ModelComboBox.DataSource = modelList;
        }
```

Comment: Also I noticed that the variable "manu" is not assigned anywhere

Comment: going to try this out now

Comment: worked!. You da boss man!  Learned something new today Thank to you  :)

Comment: Glad to know that it worked. Also, please keep in mind that IDataReader is faster in db reading than DataAdapter.

Comment: Oh is it?  I mean well My DB is only made up of two tables no bigger than a couple megs atm. But thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the display member like:

```
ModelComboBox.DataSource = bindingSource3;
ModelComboBox.DisplayMember = "ColumnName";
```

And it still shows funny values, what are the values that it shows exactly?

- Note, in a toolstrip it looks like you may have to also do:

  ModelComboBox.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;

[here is a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256832/c-sharp-fill-a-combo-box-with-a-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
ComboBox1.ItemsSource = bindingSource3
```

if this is your answer then mark it as answer