# Clear a Combo Box filled previously with a Data Source

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I filled a combo box with a DataSource, everything works as intended but now I need clear each combo box. I cant use ComboBox.Items.Clear, since I get a error saying I cant modify a item collection when a DataSource property is established (translated)

ComboBox.Items.Clear
Loop based on items.Count and remove x items

This is how I filled the combo box!

```
 Dim tabla_escenario_busqueda As New DataTable

        tabla_escenario_busqueda = Capa_de_Logica.BuscarInfoPP(txt_id_requerimiento_escenario_ver.Text) 'Llenar el combo Box
        txt_num_escenario_escenario_ver.DataSource = tabla_escenario_busqueda   'Se llena el combo box
        txt_num_escenario_escenario_ver.DisplayMember = "numero_escenario"
        'Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729770/how-do-i-bind-data-source-to-a-combobox
```

Comment: Clear the DataSource.

Comment: Or set the DataSurce to null: `DataSource = Nothing`. Also, dispose of it if it's still alive.

Comment: Set the _DataSource = Nothing_

Answer (score 0):

Damn, I feel so dumb hahaha, thanks to [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve), [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) and [LarsTech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719186/larstech) for the answers!

```
    txt_num_paso_escenario_ver.DataSource = Nothing
    txt_num_escenario_escenario_ver.DataSource = Nothing
```