# ComboBox remaining blank after selected value

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding

I am writing a small application in C# using windows forms.  I have a combo box that I am populating by querying a database for column names to use as the values inside the combo box.  My code currently can get the values just fine, however whenever I click on the combo box it removes any text and just displays a blank 'selected option'.  I have tried multiple things to correct this (changed the database field from `char` to `varchar`), tried binding to a different dataset etc. but nothing has worked. Ive also looked at other posts on this such as 
[C# comboBox databinding - nothing happens, then it goes back to blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543595/c-sharp-combobox-databinding-nothing-happens-then-it-goes-back-to-blank?rq=1)

Below is my code, and I believe I am doing the displaymember/valuemember part wrong however I do not understand what it is that is wrong. The column name in the database is Reason and it consists of 3 values.
Any help is appreciated.

```
String ConnString =    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Portal1"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);

conn.Open();

SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select [Reason] from tblReasons", conn);
SqlDataReader reader;

reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();


dt.Columns.Add("Reason", typeof(string));

dt.Load(reader);

cboxReason.ValueMember = "Reason";
cboxReason.DisplayMember = "Reason";
cboxReason.DataSource = dt;


conn.Close();
```

Comment: Couple of questions, did you try without specifying  cboxReason.ValueMember = "Reason"; cboxReason.DisplayMember = "Reason"; And, Are you sure there is data in "dt"

Comment: Have you tried `dt.DefaultView`?

Comment: Can you post a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because there is nothing wrong with your code. I have tried it and everything works fine - comboBox is filled and never loses its values. Perhaps you are doing something else with this comboBox?

Comment: I agree with @Eugene, it **should** work though I haven't tried it. Maybe post a screenshot of what exactly happens with the combo box?

Comment: Thank you guys for looking at this with me.  I tried the above (and below) solutions and nothing worked so I started at step 1 again.
I fixed my problem, and it turns out that when created the database to draw values from I had set the type to char(50).  When I changed this to varchar I forgot to manually remove all the white space created by the char.  This in turn meant that when I went to grab that information from the database the return string would be to long to fit into the combo box field which made it remain blank.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks OK.  I would not add the column, that should happen automatically.  Here is my sample code that works:

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);

        conn.Open();

        var reader = new SqlCommand("select ID from Users", conn).ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(reader);

        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ID";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
```

Note: This populates with the list of **values** in the column.  For the list of column names, I would suggest changing your query to return a list of columns for the table (DB specific query) **OR** look at the **DataTable.Columns** collection for the column names.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the answer from [C# - Fill a combo box with a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256832/c-sharp-fill-a-combo-box-with-a-datatable)

```
cboxReason.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```