# Bind column from datatable to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to bind DataTable column to combobox, I have DataTable Names "Types" with one column, the header of this column is "Type".

I have tried the following:

```
private DataTable dt;
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   dt=Query();// return datatable from the database
   myComboBox.DataContext =dt;
}
```

but the combobox is still empty (the datatable isn't)

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/256871/10705051) answer, but in my C# wpf I have no `myComboBox.ComboBox.DataSource` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private DataTable dt;
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   dt=Query();// return datatable from the database
   myComboBox.ItemsSource = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["Type"].ToString()).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ComboBox.ItemsSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource).

You can set it directly if your `DataTable` inherits from `IEnumerable`, otherwise create a `List` from your `DataTable`.

Example code (assuming that `DataTable` inherits from `IEnumerable`):

```
myComboBox.ItemsSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
this.myComboBox.datasource=dt;
```